# Extract each year, month, day, year from getctime , getmtime in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to extract the year month day hours min eachly from  below value.

```
import os, time, os.path, datetime

date_of_created = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(folderName))
date_of_modi = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(folderName))
```

Now I only can get like below
'Thu Dec 26 19:21:37 2019' 
but I want to get the the value separtly 
2019 // Dec(Could i get this as int??) // 26
each

I want to extract each year month day each time min value from date_of_created and date_of_modi
Could i get it? in python?

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the string to a datetime object:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_of_created = datetime.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(folderName)), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") # Convert string to date format
print("Date created year: {} , month: {} , day: {}".format(str(date_of_created.year),str(date_of_created.month),str(date_of_created.day)))
```

Comment: `import time` also required.

Answer (score 1):

The [`time.ctime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.ctime) function returns the local time in `string` form. You might want to use the [`time.localtime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.localtime) function, which returns a [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) object which contains the information you are looking for. As example,

```
import os, time

date_created_string = time.ctime(os.path.getctime('/home/b-fg/Downloads'))
date_created_obj = time.localtime(os.path.getctime('/home/b-fg/Downloads'))
print(date_created_string) # Mon Feb 10 09:41:03 2020
print('Year: {:4d}'.format(date_created_obj.tm_year)) # Year: 2020
print('Month: {:2d}'.format(date_created_obj.tm_mon)) # Month:  2
print('Day: {:2d}'.format(date_created_obj.tm_mday)) # Day: 10
```

Note that these are `integer` values, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  time.ctime([secs])
> ```
>
> Convert a time expressed in seconds since the epoch to a string of a form: 'Sun Jun 20 23:21:05 1993' representing local time.

If that's not what you want... use something else? `time.getmtime` will return a `struct_time` which should have the relevant fields, or for a more modern interface use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` which... returns a `datetime` object from a UNIX timestamp.

Furthermore, using `stat` would probably more efficient as it ctime and mtime will probably perform a `stat` call each internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datetime module, more specifically the `fromtimestamp()` function from the datetime module to get what you expect.

```py
import os, time, os.path, datetime

date_of_created = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(my_repo))
date_of_modi = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(my_repo))

print(date_of_created.strftime("%Y"))
```

Output will be `2020` for a repo created in 2020.

All formats are available at this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Comment: I tried but i got AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime' this message

Comment: ```datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()``` returns a datetime object. Check the code you applied and the one in this solution. You surely convert your datetime to a string somewhere.